# Change the dimensionality of a 3-D data type in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have this data of type 3-D in matlab with the dimensions (100,100,100). I want to reshape this data such that I only want the data of dimension (100, 2:10,100). How can I do this in matlab?

Comment: that doesnt make sense; when reshaping a matrix the number of elements must not change (100*100*100 for the first, cannot become 100*9*100 in the second)

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is your 100x100x100 matrix, you can use:

```
    B = A(:,2:10,:);
```

B is then a 100x9x100 matrix consisting of A's data of the corresponding entries.